# Why doesn't Visual Studio notice changes to packages.config on build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm not very familiar with Nuget, especially against VC++. I realised I needed to add Curl to my executable simply because it links a library using Curl.
So I edited the .exe's package.config:

```
  <package id="Curl" version="7.59.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
  <package id="Curl.redist" version="7.59.0.0" targetFramework="native" />
```

But *again* I am having to jump into the Nuget console in VS to update/restore things first. Why isn't this happening automatically? Is it possible to make it work that way?

Worse still, running `update-package` tells me there are no updates required. I have to reinstall them every time.

Comment: I don't understand nuget's integration with c++ projects, but with .NET, it's not a valid workflow to manually edit packages.config. You must use the Package Manager UI to install, as NuGet will not only edit packages.config, but also the project file. For .NET projects, PackageReference changes will be detected automatically at build, so that can be edited manually, but I know that c++ projects don't support PackageReference.

Comment: @zivkan thanks for that. I noticed when I reinstall, other projects in my solution now show up as changed in my local Git which is not something I want!

Comment: when you look at the diff, what are the changes? the only reason reinstalling packages in a .NET project would cause a change to the project file is if the packages were never correctly installed in the first place. If you commit the changes, then reinstall a second time, git won't show any changes. Like I said, I know basically nothing about how nuget is supposed to work with VC projects.

Answer (score 1):

> Why isn't this happening automatically? Is it possible to make it work
>   that way?

As **zivkan** said, it's not a valid workflow to **manually** edit packages.config so it's not happening automatically. And if you have to consume nuget packages in this way by manually `adding and editing` `packages.config` file, you can `right-click the solution in solution explorer` and click `Restore Nuget Packages` to restore packages first.

> running update-package tells me there are no updates required

For `Curl`, in [Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/curl/) there's only `7.30.0.2`(latest) version which depends on `Curl.redist-7.30.0.2` version. I'm not sure where you can find the `7.59.0` version (It seems it has been released,see [here](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2018-03/0058.html)), but it's obviously not published to `nuget.org`. So when you try to restore nuget packages from available nuget source in `nuget console` or Solution's `Restore Nuget packages` option mentioned above, you'll get `no updates required` or error like `unable to find version 7.59.0 of package curl`.

To resolve this issue, you can go `Tools menu=>Nuget Package Manager=>Package Manager Settings=>Package Sources` to configure the source where to find the `7.59.0 version of Curl`. Then you can use the `Restore nuget packages` option to restore them easily for all projects in the solution. Or you can just trying changing the version `7.59.0.0` to the `7.30.0.2` which is exactly available in nuget.org.